# Python list elements showing individual characters (Pandas DF from CSV)

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, csv

I have a .csv with a 'cities' column. The column's values are supposed to be a list with each element being a list itself in the following format:

```
['City', (latitude, longitude)]
```

So for example:

```
[['Athens', (37.9839412, 23.7283052)], ['Heraklion', (35.3400127, 25.1343475)], ['Mykonos', (37.45142265, 25.392303200095327)]]
```

I am trying to load the csv into a pandas dataframe using pd.read_csv().
The value in the column ends up with type string and looks like this:

```
'[[\'Athens\', (37.9839412, 23.7283052)], [\'Heraklion\', (35.3400127, 25.1343475)], [\'Mykonos\', (37.45142265, 25.392303200095327)]]'
```

However, because its a string, its just seeing each element as one character.
When I do:

```
for i in cities:
  print(i)
```

Or:

```
list(cities)
```

I get:

```
[
[
'
A
t
h
e
n
s
'
,
 
(
3
7
.
9
8
3
9
4
1
2
,
 
2
3
.
7
2
8
3
0
5
2
)
]
,
```

etc.

I am looking for a way to 're-build' the data back into python list format so that I can access the string 'Athens' with df.loc[0]['cities][0] and the tuple (37.9839412, 23.7283052) with df.loc[0]['cities][1].

I have tried df['cities'].astype(list) which results in the error:

```
TypeError: dtype '<class 'list'>' not understood
```

Comment: Your data isn't really a .CSV format.  Can you fix upstream to not write that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the data is a string that looks like a Python array. You can access the values for this using `ast.literal_eval` by applying this [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function on every row in the DataFrame and storing the output city and coordinates as separate columns in the DataFrame.

Comment: Wow! That is exactly what I was looking for! You're a lifesaver! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that it's currently a `string`, rather than a `list`. Simply implement this:

```py
import ast

l = '[[\'Athens\', (37.9839412, 23.7283052)], [\'Heraklion\', (35.3400127, 25.1343475)], [\'Mykonos\', (37.45142265, 25.392303200095327)]]'
res = ast.literal_eval(l)
print(res)
print(type(res))
```

```
Output:
[['Athens', (37.9839412, 23.7283052)], ['Heraklion', (35.3400127, 25.1343475)], ['Mykonos', (37.45142265, 25.392303200095327)]]
<class 'list'>
```